# IIS 8 on Windows 2012 R2 asks client for a cetificate

Tags: windows-server-2012, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I have newly installed Windows Server  2012 R2 with IIS 8. I have added a SSL certificate through pfx file and when I try to access the site with browser I get this promt that asks client for certificate. It happens in Edge, safari and chrome. This is not desired, all I wanted was to have an SSL connection.

Do you have an idea what might be causing this?

Thank you

[the promnt from edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPDrp.png)

Comment: How you installed the certificate ? your prompt look like a smartcard prompt for authentification against the IIS

Comment: It sounds like you have the site configured to require client certificates, which is probably not what you want. Check the SSL settings for the site and make sure it's correct and appropriate.

Comment: Hi, I firstly added manually certificates to  intermediate certificate authority. Then i realized i had pfx file and i ran that. After i set proper binding in my default app pool this started to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. Out of my own stupidity I had acccept SSL certificate set to "Accept" instead of "Ignore".